# Using powershell to count number of files in subfolder with specific name

Tags: file, powershell, filter, count, subdirectory

So I've started working on a problem where I need to know how many files are in a subfolder of a certain name, that is repeated multiple times in throughout the directory. All folders I want to count have the same name. For example:

```
Main Folder
    Subfolder
        Folder I want to count
        Folder A
        Folder B
    Subfolder
        Folder I want to count
        Folder C
        Folder D
```

I'm able to count the number of files in all subfolders recursively, but I don't know how to only look at folders named " *Folder I want to count* ".

This is where I've gotten so far to count everything. What do I need to add/modify to only look at and count in the area I want. I'm not familiar with supershell, and have been working to make sense of various questions and cobble this together.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Group Directory | Format-Table Name, Count -autosize
```

Comment: Do the "folder I want to count" all have the same name, or any other similarities?

Comment: All the folders I want to count have the same name. Sorry, I'll edit and clarify that.

Comment: Get-childitem -filter Directoryname -Directory -Recurse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this.

First get all the folders, then run through them. And if the folder is the "folder_I_want", get the count.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\David\Documents\SAPIEN\test -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select name, fullname

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    #Write-Host "$folder"
    if ($folder.name -eq "folder_I_want")
    {
        $fullname = $folder.fullname
        #Gets the count of the files in "Folder I want". It will filter out folders.
        $count = (Get-ChildItem $fullname | where { $_.PSIsContainer -EQ $false }).count
        Write-Host "The amount of files in the folder I want: $count"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really close to what I need! What would I add in the output line to report the full directory path?

Comment: For example:

"The amount of files in the [FULL DIRECTORY PATH] is $count"

Sorry for the double comment. Still new to SO.

Comment: It's already defined as $fullname. So this would work:

`write-host "The amount of files in the path $fullname is $count"`

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

somthing like this?

```
(gci -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -File | where fullname -like "*\yourname\*").Count
```