# Powershell: Get count of file and folder from a directory

Tags: powershell

I need to get the count of files and directories. I am aware we have some options to get the count like below.

```
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder | Measure-Object ).Count;
```

Or

```
$headers = @{ $true='Folder'; $false='File' }
Get-ChildItem |
  Group-Object PSIsContainer |
  Select-Object @{ Name="Type"; Expression={ $headers[$_.Name -eq $true] } }, Count
```

Or

```
$filepath = "c:\MyFolder"
$filetype = "*.txt"
$file_count = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("$filepath", "$filetype").Count
```

The thing is, it is taking too much time to get the count.
For example, if we would like to get the number of directories and files from C:\Windows.
it is taking too much time.

Is there any other way to get the same that can give the results faster?

Comment: Using `System.IO.Directory` is as fast as I have ever been able to get it. Using `du -v` from sysinternals on `c:\windows` also takes a minute and I doubt you can get much faster than that. I'd love to proven wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will dig more about System.IO.Directory.do i need to install anything for du -v.

Comment: Download the [sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/) tools. du is part of that set.

Answer (score 0):

found one more, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40052013/8850237

```
(gci -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -File | where fullname -like "*\yourname\*").Count
```

to ignore errors (I ran it on c:\ got a lot of permission denied errors)

```
(gci -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where fullname -like "*\yourname\*").Count
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it takes lot of time. I need to get the information faster. I have used this command.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you already started asking questions at this stage, Powershell is slow. So it's time to move on to using .net objects in your code. They work faster.